# Код в VS2017 выглядит как простой текст

Tags: visual-studio, текст, razor

Собственно говоря, сабж. Свежая Студия воспринимает код в .cshtml как plain text и ведёт себя соответственно. Как ей указать, что это вообще-то файл с кодом, а не какой-то .txt? IntelliSense пашет, что интересно. Т.е. вопрос только к хайлайту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а файл точно cshtml?

Comment: Попробуй разные цветовые схемы

Comment: @Grundy, на скриншоте - layout свежесозданного проекта. Так что да(

Comment: На скриншоте виден код, но не видно имя и расширение файла.

Comment: Тоже верно) Не помогло. XML/html/css и прочие подсветка корректная

Comment: Ты пробовал и светлые и темные?

Comment: Да, все четыре перепробовал. Фигня в том, что он сам файл как чистый текст воспринимает

Comment: [тут говорят что может быть из-за F# установленного](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/47876/dark-theme-broke-over-the-weekend-unusable.html) либо из-за стороннего плагина

Comment: если б был чистый текст, то не работал бы IntelliSense

Comment: F# я отродясь не ставил, а переключение темы не спасло

Comment: Проверь, может он по умолчанию ставился. Ну и заведи issue там :-)